# UnicodeDecodeError on PHP + GAE

Tags: php, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I'm losing any resources about this could any one help me.

basically I have system that currently uploaded on cloud via Google App Engine and I use PHP, and I haven't encounter such error on uploading until now, after couple of days fixing some issue on my site I want to upload changes then it lead me to this error

```
02:46 PM Uploading 36 files and blobs.
2014-07-02 14:46:19,551 ERROR appcfg.py:2488 An unexpected error occurred. Aborting. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2329, in DoUpload
    self._UploadMissingFiles(missing_files, openfunc)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2455, in _UploadMissingFiles
    self.UploadFile(missing_file, file_handle)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2002, in UploadFile
    file_classification.StaticMimeType())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1442, in AddToBatch
    self.SendSingleFile(path, payload, mime_type)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1388, in SendSingleFile
    path=path)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1684, in Send
    result = self.rpcserver.Send(url, payload=payload, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 408, in Send
    HttpRequestToString(req, include_data=self.debug_data))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 102, in HttpRequestToString
    'data': req.get_data(),
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 307343: ordinal not in range(128)
02:46 PM Rolling back the update.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 126, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 122, in run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5220, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5211, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2886, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 4890, in __call__
    return method()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3682, in Update
    self._UpdateWithParsedAppYaml(appyaml, self.basepath)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3735, in _UpdateWithParsedAppYaml
    self.UpdateVersion(rpcserver, basepath, appyaml, APP_YAML_FILENAME)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3618, in UpdateVersion
    return appversion.DoUpload(paths, openfunc)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2329, in DoUpload
    self._UploadMissingFiles(missing_files, openfunc)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2455, in _UploadMissingFiles
    self.UploadFile(missing_file, file_handle)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2002, in UploadFile
    file_classification.StaticMimeType())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1442, in AddToBatch
    self.SendSingleFile(path, payload, mime_type)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1388, in SendSingleFile
    path=path)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1684, in Send
    result = self.rpcserver.Send(url, payload=payload, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 408, in Send
    HttpRequestToString(req, include_data=self.debug_data))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 102, in HttpRequestToString
    'data': req.get_data(),
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 307343: ordinal not in range(128)
2014-07-02 14:46:21 (Process exited with code 1)

You can close this window now.
```

and this is my app.yaml

```
url: /assets/lib/parsley/(.*\.md)
  static_files: assets/lib/parsley/\1
  upload: assets/lib/parsley/(.*\.md)
  mime_type: text/x-markdown

- url: /assets/lib/nvd3/(.*\.md)
  static_files: assets/lib/nvd3/\1
  upload: assets/lib/nvd3/(.*\.md)
  mime_type: text/x-markdown

- url: /assets/js/(.*\.json)
  static_files: assets/js/\1
  upload: assets/js/(.*\.json)
  mime_type: application/json

- url: /assets/lib/examples/(.*\.json)
  static_files: assets/lib/examples/\1
  upload: assets/lib/examples/(.*\.json)
  mime_type: application/json

- url: /assets/css/fonts/glyphicons/(.*\.(eot|ttf|woff))
  static_files: assets/css/fonts/glyphicons/\1
  upload: assets/css/fonts/glyphicons/(.*\.(eot|ttf|woff))
  mime_type: application/x-woff

- url: /assets/css/fonts/font-awesome/(.*\.(eot|ttf|woff|otf))
  static_files: assets/css/fonts/font-awesome/\1
  upload: assets/css/fonts/font-awesome/(.*\.(eot|ttf|woff|otf))
  mime_type: application/font-woff 

- url: /assets/css/fontello/font/(.*\.(eot|ttf|woff))
  static_files: assets/css/fontello/font/\1
  upload: assets/css/fontello/font/(.*\.(eot|ttf|woff))
  mime_type: application/x-woff

- url: /assets/css/font/(.*\.(eot|ttf|woff))
  static_files: assets/css/font/\1
  upload: assets/css/font/(.*\.(eot|ttf|woff))
  mime_type: application/x-woff

- url: /assets/css
  static_dir: assets/css

- url: /assets/js
  static_dir: assets/js

- url: /assets/lib
  static_dir: assets/lib

- url: /assets/img
  static_dir: assets/img

- url: /.*
  script: index.php
  secure: always
```

I don't know any python related stuff I just used PHP, javascript, and Google app engine.

Could anyone help me what cause of `UnicodeDecodeError`. 
also what could I do to fix this?

any suggestion and information would be a big help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you have a file that is part of your app that has unicode characters in it's name, and this stops your app from uploading.

The fix would be to rename the file to use ascii characters.